# POSTing JSON data to WCF Rest Service

Tags: ajax, rest, http-post

I know there are many questions on SO about this but none of the suggestions have worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
var restService = "http://wcfrestservice:8004/RADPOCService/WebApp1";
$.ajax({
    url: restService,
    type: "POST",
    data: { PhoneNumber: y },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: 
      function (data) {
        window.open(data.Url, '_blank');
      }
});
```

Fiddler shows my request going across the wire like so (redacted):

```
POST http://localhost:8004/RADPOCService/WebApp1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8004
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
Accept: application/json, text/javascript; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8000/Default.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Requestor: Me

PhoneNumber=1234567890
```

I am expecting the payload to look like this:

```
{ "PhoneNumber": "1234567890"}
```

When I set the payload as above in the Fiddler Composer tab the service works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to do this so quickly after posting my question but the answer is to use the JSON.stringify API on the data being sent to the service. So the above should have the following code for 'data' in the ajax call:`data: JSON.stringify({ PhoneNumber: y })`